# Ruby While method not stopping loop from Twitter GEM

Tags: ruby, twitter

been messing around with some Twitter scripts that I found online and I'm trying to get a loop to stop after 5 tweet favorites, but it's not stopping. Any pointers on how to fix the loop?
    i = 0
    while i < 5
        begin

```
        config = {
            consumer_key:        '',
            consumer_secret:     '',
            access_token:        '',
            access_token_secret: ''
        }
        rClient = Twitter::REST::Client.new config
        sClient = Twitter::Streaming::Client.new(config)
        # topics to watch
        topics = ['#rails', '#ruby', '#coding', '#codepen']
        sClient.filter(:track => topics.join(',')) do |tweet|
            if tweet.is_a?(Twitter::Tweet)
              puts tweet.text 
              rClient.fav tweet
       i+=1
            end
        end
    rescue
        puts 'error occurred, waiting for 5 seconds'
        sleep 5
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `i` will stop the while loop, but it will not stop your client from iterating (because it was all done with in 1 `while` literation). Try:

```
    sClient.filter(:track => topics.join(',')) do |tweet|
        break if i >= 5
        if tweet.is_a?(Twitter::Tweet)
          puts tweet.text 
          rClient.fav tweet
          i+=1
        end
    end
```

You should not need the while loop.